# Gradle project sync failed with no event log

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, libgdx

I have a libGDX project generated by the gdx-setup.jar tool, including core, android, desktop, and html modules. I hadn't touched any of the gradle files, and my build has worked fine for some weeks.

This morning when I opened IntelliJ IDEA (build 135.1230), it offered to update the Scala plugin, so I accepted and restarted, before trying to open the project. My libGDX project doesn't use Scala at all: I have the plugin for other work. When I tried to open the project, I got the infamous "Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly" message. Clicking "Try again" thinks for a bit before showing the same message. The Event Log window contains no output, and the Messages window says:

> Error: (of class java.lang.String)

The Scala plugin isn't the only thing that might have changed: I've rebooted the (Ubuntu) machine since the project last worked, so it's possible that some package updates might have only just had an effect.

Following the advice of others, I've tried editing the root gradle.properties to change `org.gradle.configureondemand` to `false`, and that made no difference. I've tried performing "Build → Clean Project" and "Invalidate and Restart", with the same effect. I've also tried running `git clean -X` and reimporting the Gradle project into IDEA, but I just get a "Resolve error" dialog with the same message as above.

Running a build command like

```
./gradlew android:assemble
```

from a shell still works fine: only IntelliJ IDEA has a problem.

Even if you've never seen this particular problem, I'd appreciate any tips on where to start debugging it. The error message doesn't exactly give me a lot to go on.

Comment: This happened to me as well, after installing the most recent scala plugin update (version 0.41) for IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: The fact that it works from the command line lets you know your gradle files are fine, and the project itself is still fine. What version of IntelliJ are you on? Also, can you remove the Scala plugin and try reimporting the project?

Comment: I started seeing this after upgrading too, so I've entered an issue: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-7415